# Как быстро расставить точки с запятой, имея 10000 строк кода...?

Tags: javascript

Коротко:

---

Нужно автоматически ПРАВИЛЬНО расставить "точку с запятой" в javascript библиотеке.

---

Длинно:

---

Появилась весьма интересная проблема. Делаю редактор кода онлайн, решил использовать *code mirror*.
И возникает весьма интересный вопрос. Как сжать библиотеку?
Проблема в "особом" стиле написания кода... Там редко используются точки-запятые.
Компрессору, соответственно, нужен нормальный код.

---

Подскажите, что делать. Может, есть регулярки какие-то для Python или PHP?
Или есть уже минимизированная версия..?

Пример того ужасного (по моему мнению) кода:

```
var gecko = /gecko\/\d/i.test(userAgent)
var ie_upto10 = /MSIE \d/.test(userAgent)
var ie_11up = /Trident\/(?:[7-9]|\d{2,})\..*rv:(\d+)/.exec(userAgent)
var edge = /Edge\/(\d+)/.exec(userAgent)
var ie = ie_upto10 || ie_11up || edge
```

Comment: В python, хвала Ван Россуму, можно и нужно писать без точек с запятой, правда, интерпретатор "понимает" их.

Comment: Да в js тоже) Проблема-то в том, что код весь при сокращении вытягивается в строку. А тут уж без точек с запятыми- никак

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону обфускаторов. По идее для обфускации нужно спарсить синтаксис, а значит они могут знать где поставить `;`

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/jshint/fixmyjs

Comment: кстати, писать js без точек с запятой сейчас в тренде. вот, скажем, исходники mobx https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/core/atom.ts, хороший читаемый код. в общем то, точка с запятой обязательна только в паре случае, к примеру перед самовызывающейся функций (self-invocation которая)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день

Если требуется сжать js, то можно использоваться библиотеку типа uglify-js. Их несколько и они доступны также и в виде плагинов. Проставлять точки с запятой заранее не потребуется. Главное, чтобы код был валидным.

Если требуется проверить и исправить качество своего/чужого кода, можно прогнать файлы через prettier.

PS.
кстати, писать js без точек с запятой сейчас в тренде. вот, скажем, исходники mobx https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/core/atom.ts, хороший читаемый код. в общем то, точка с запятой обязательна только в паре случае, к примеру перед самовызывающейся функций (self-invocation которая). Это скорее вопрос привычки к тому или иному стилю.

Comment: хотя уверен, что главным вопросом о стиле кода навсегда останется вопрос о `{ `: на той же строке или на новой? =D

Comment: в основном- да)